Ubuntu 22.04 Slow
I have a problem related to performance. When starting Ubuntu it starts quickly and in approximately 15 seconds of use, it becomes slow, delays when opening folders, settings. Whatever the actions, I noticed a pattern. When suspending and log in again, performance returns to normal and in 15 seconds it becomes slow.
I've already reformatted it to 24.04 and 22.04, but nothing resolved it. Note: The system was super fast and there was no delay at all. Before the release of 24.04 there were no problems. I made a suggested update, and since then even formatting has not been as usual.
   System: Ubuntu 22.04.04
   Hardware: Dell Inspiron 3543
   CPU: Intel i5-5200U 2.20GHz x 4 Processor
   RAM: 8GB (only 1 RAM slot)
   SSD: 240GB Sata Bx500 Model: CT240BX500SSD1 (M6CR056)
   Graphics: Intel HD 5500 (BDW GT2)
   OS Type: 64-bit
   Motherboard: Dell Inc. 0MPND5 Version A00
I formatted it to 22.04.03 to start with kernel 6.2 with Grub Customizer I installed the preload I deactivated Iommu I deactivated Turbo Boost, tested and reactivated I deactivated Thermald, tested and reactivated. I performed an SSD performance and integrity test. It's OK all OK Processor temperature test, OK (38° to 49°) Install versions before and after 22.04.04 (lowest installed version - 22.04.03) - (highest installed version - 24.04.04).
I consulted through htop , gnome-shell easily reaching 59% of cpu just by moving the mouse.

This is a Q&A site for Questions and Answers that are more generally applicable. For this type of rather specific, personal and hardware related problems that require an individual diagnosis, you may have more success on https://ubuntuforums.org/. A forum is a more interactive form, where it is more easy for people to ask you information in a stepwise form to come to a solution.

After many analyses, I realized that when I exited the suspend screen the speed returned to normal, however within a few seconds of use, it became extremely slow, this made me seek to find out what was happening with the processor, it seemed more like a limitation , I started htop showing the thread frequencies and realized that it was no more than 498-500 Mhz, something was limiting the processor, I used the command "stress -c 4" to force maximum use, threads at their normal speed of 2700 Mhz but when the temperature reached 62 to 70 degrees all the speed and temperature dropped, I decided to access bios via terminal and access was denied, I resorted to starting with F12 and selecting the diagnostic option, there it showed that the cooler was not working correctly, just change it and the problem will resolve itself.

Have you checked top and/or iotop (may need to install it) to see what process is the bottleneck.  It sounds like either thermal throttling or some process is taking all the resources and/or thrashing on your had drive.
from a terminal:
top

sudo iotop

